# How to get bytes to JavaScript from a Rust function?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly

I have a part of code written in Rust and I want to get some bytes in JS.

`file.rs`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_char_successfully() -> char {
    'a'
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_bytes_unsuccessfully() -> String {
    String::from("string");
}
```

`file.js`:

```js
const rs = await import('../file-rs.wasm')
let a = rs.get_char_successfully(); // work
let b = get_bytes_unsuccessfully(); // not working, empty
```

I use wasm-pack

Comment: Are you using wasm-pack or something?

Comment: I use wasm-pack

Comment: I am by no means a Rust expert, but don't you have to call `.bytes()` to get bytes from a String?